# JavaFX bind two RadioButtons with contrary selection

Tags: javafx, radio-button

I am new in JavaFX.. I have two `javafx.scene.control.RadioButton` and I want them to bind that way, when one is getting selected, that the other isn't selected and vice versa.

If I bind it that way

```
radioButton1.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(radioButton2.selectedProperty())
```

both are either selected or not.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't you just put them into a `ToggleGroup`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add both `RadioButton`s to the same toggle group:

```
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
radioButton1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
radioButton2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```